# Fastest way to find if same struct exist in a vector

Tags: c++, c, vector, struct

Lets suppose that I have a persons struct:

```
struct Person {
    char name[100];
    char surname[100];
    unsigned int age;
};
```

I would like to find out the fastest way to search and find if another struct with the same values (same name, same surname, same age) already exist in a vector.

Please keep in mind that I have million of those in a vector.

Thanks

Comment: Try to put items of `vector` to a `set`, and use `set`'s fast find.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: How can I sort the vector? I mean can I sort it against name or surname or age if I need everything to match?

Comment: If it is already sorted on all of the above fields through a comprehensive comparator or `operator <()`, a simple binary search will work. If it is not, the minimum time taken will be O(N) and require a linear scan, though you can exit early the moment you find a presence; ironic that determining it is *not* in your vector will take the longest of all). I would advise a comprehensive `operator <()` and a `std::set<>` rather than a `vector<>`if this is going to be a frequent operation. Build time is O(NlogN), but search time is reduced to O(logN).

Comment: And a million of anything this small is near-nothing so long as you void the dreaded O(N^2) or worse algorithms.

Comment: @salamis So can you change your base container to be a `std::set<Person>` (or std::`unordered_set<Person>` if order is unimportant)? if so, if will modify the "build container" code somewhat, but also make this search request trivial. Consider whether you need the other features of a `std::vector<>` before going this route (random access, linear sequenced layout, etc.).

Comment: Hello @WhozCraig I can change it to set if this will result to a better performance.

Comment: Is it ever random-accessed (i.e. `vec[n]`, or require persistent iterators? If all you're using it for is collecting unique instances of a Person structure (such as from a file), then a set or unordered-set will be likely idea for you.

Comment: I want it in order to identify duplicates while reading from a file and keep a separate set for all duplicates for example if line 1 is the same with line 10 I would like to have only one item in my vector or set and a separate set storing all duplicates.

Comment: When you say duplicates, you mean something that denotes a counter or something similar that indicates how many times the item was in the file?

Comment: No, I mean a set which describes that 10 was duplicate to 2, 12, 54, etc or 2 was duplicate to 10, 12, 54.

Comment: OK yeah, a set won't help you with that without adding read-number data to the Person construct. I assume the numbers above are lines or occurrence order in your input file; 2 is the second item read, 10 is he 10th item read, etc. A set will help you filter out the duplicates, but you will need a special node type to handle the kind of thing you're talking about, especially since the my-duplicates list can grow dynamically for each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>

struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    unsigned int age;

    bool operator<(const Person &x) const
    {
        return std::tie(name, surname, age) < std::tie(x.name, x.surname, x.age);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> v;

    // ...

    std::set<Person> s;
    for (const auto &x : v)
    {
        auto i = s.insert(x);
        if (!i.second)
        {
            // x is duplicated
        }
    }
}
```

To your comment, you can sort your vector by this way:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); // Operator < is overloaded
```

Comment: The `.find()` logic can be eliminated and simply use `.insert()`. It will `.find()` for you, and if the item is already present, skip the new insertion and keep the original. Even then, the iterator returned wil include a `bool` indicating whether the insertion was new.

Comment: Can the find return the position of the element? Or at least an attribute for example name as I can use an Id attribute to remember duplicates as I will need them later. Additionally can you explain me why I will need a Vector and a set at the same time?

Comment: @salamis `.insert()` will return a `std::pair<iterator,bool>`. The `bool` indicates whether the insertion was new. If it is `false`, then it was *not* new and was rather already present in the set. See the [docs on `std::set<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) for more info.

Comment: I like your very nice implementation of `bool operator<`. Very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the question, specifically

> No, I mean a set which describes that 10 was duplicate to 2, 12, 54, etc or 2 was duplicate to 10, 12, 54

it sounds like the data structure you actually want is `std::multimap` (or `std::unordered_multimap` if you have C++11 and don't care about order). Multimaps will take care of the bookkeeping you would have to do on your own with M M.'s solution (which is nice overall, except that you have to maintain an additional container with duplicate description). `std::multimap` does the extra bookkeeping for you.

```
#include <map>     // or <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>   // std::tie()
#include <utility> // std::make_pair()

struct Person {
  std::string name;
  std::string surname;
  unsigned int age;

  bool operator<(const Person &x) const
  {
    return std::tie(name, surname, age) < std::tie(x.name, x.surname, x.age);
  }
};

extern bool tryReadNextPersonFromFile(Person &, size_t & record_id);

int main()
{
  std::multimap<Person, size_t> persons;
  Person p;
  size_t rid;

  while(tryReadNextPersonFromFile(p, rid)) {
    persons.insert(std::make_pair(p, rid));
  }

  // ...

  p = ...
  size_t howMany = persons.count(p);
  if(0 == howMany) { /* not found ... */ }
  else {
    auto eq_range = persons.equal_range(p);
    for(auto it=eq_range.first; it != eq_range.second; ++it) {
      size_t pRecordID = it->second;
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using a lot of C++11 syntax (like `auto`) for brevity, but this idea works just as well for C++03. Since you probably haven't heard of multimaps before (or at least are unfamiliar with the STL interface), be sure to check out eg, [some documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/) on what you can do with it and how.